# When i try to use pyinstaller it claims that it's not installed, when i try to install it it claims it's already installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pyinstaller

So the title explains it all.

```
C:\Users\username>py -m pip install  pyinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2019.4.18)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller) (0.18.2)

C:\Users\username>py -m pyinstaller
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller
```

NOTES:
I use py instead of python because python doesn't work for an unknown reason

```
C:\Users\username>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\username>py
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Invoking  just "pyinstaller" doesn't work neither it does for pip

```
C:\Users\username>pip
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\username>py -m pip

Usage:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe -m pip <command> [options]
(...)

C:\Users\username>pyinstaller
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'd like to know why these things work differently for other people as well.

Comment: I've managed to fix the 'py' problem but pyinstaller not working although being installed hasn't been resorted.

Answer (score 0):

Read those instruction from main page https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Try install by **pip install pyinstaller**. if leads to numpy error then downgrade the pyinstaller version to 3.4 by **pip install pyinstaller==3.4**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has the same problem the solution of installing different version works.
After that you can do **pip install --upgrade pyinstaller** and it will be up-to-date and working, no idea why...